# Debug Azure Devops powershell scripts locally in VSCode

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, powershell-core

Judging from the `Debugging Azure Functions` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-powershell-local, it looks possible. Can somebody post a detailed example?

Let's say we have pipeline that run the Build.ps1. The script installs other `PS` modules builds my Visual studio solution and creates the installer.

The installer part breaks so I guess I have to use a `Wait-Debugger` before it and try to somehow attach to the agent powershell process. But oi am not certain how to do it.

Comment: Your link has an example.

Comment: The link is about Azure Functions and not Azure DevOps

Comment: What specific debugging functionality are you after? I’ve certainly debugged my DevOps PS scripts locally but I had to add some extra code to set up a test bed

Comment: I want to attach the debugger in vs-code and examine variable, step in-out etc

Comment: I’m not aware of any special test bed. I just inspected variables to see if I’m running in DevOps or not, and if not, I manually set required variables to allow it to run locally.

Comment: This has nothing to do with attching the remote `ps` process as described in the doc link I posted.

Comment: In future please describe what you want in the original question.

Comment: I’d be very surprised if DevOps Cloud hosted agents would let an external remote client connect to a running process.Happy to be wrong though.